# How to FTP certain number of files to 3 seperate directories on an FTP server using BATCH command line

Tags: command-line, batch-file, ftp, command, batch-processing

I was wondering if it is possible to count have many files are in a directory, divide the number of files by 3 and then ftp the files to 3 seprate folders on a web server?r 2

EX.  If I have 21 files in a folder, I need the script to find out how many files are in there, then divide by 3.  I then need to FTP first 7 to folder1 on ftp server, upload files 8-14 to folder number 2, and upload the last 7 files to folder number 3.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What batch language are you using (windows, linux, etc)?

Comment: what is your programming question? is it dividing by three? is it deciding on the naming of the destination folder? is it the upload procedure? what have you tried? what was the problem you had?

Answer (score 1):

The Windows Batch file below do what you want in a local (same computer) folder. You may adjust the details for this to work over a network.

```
@echo off
rem Following line is required to use !var! value into FOR loops:
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Count the files:
set fileCount=0
for %%f in (*.*) do set /A fileCount+=1

rem Copy files to folder!folder!; increment folder every filesPerFolder=fileCount/3
set /A filesPerFolder=fileCount/3
set folder=1
set i=0
for %%f in (*.*) do (
    copy %%f folder!folder!
    set /A i+=1
    if !i! == %filesPerFolder% set /A folder+=1, i=0
)
```